# PHP: chaining methods with variable methods

Tags: php, methods

Here is my code:

```
return PDF::loadFile($url)
    ->setPaper('a4')
    ->setOption('margin-top', 10)
    ->stream('somefile.pdf');
```

As I am calling this method on multiple locations, is there some kind of option to call it in a way like this?

```
return PDF::loadFile($url)
    ->callSettings()
    ->stream('somefile.pdf');
```

Where the settings are `->setPaper('a4')->setOption('margin-top', 10)`.

Comment: you have to make a method "callSettings" in the object returned by PDF::loadFile() (I guess it is a PDF...). If so, make a method in the class PDF returning this->setPaper('a4')->setOption('margin-top', 10) (you may have to use `self::` instead of `$this->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Just implement a new `callSettings()` method in `PDF` class, that calls those methods and returns `$this`:

```
public function callSettings()
{
    $this->setPaper('a4')
         ->setOption('margin-top', 10);

    return $this;
}
```